# Главный класс для проекта ... не настроен

Tags: ide, java, netbeans

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    } 
}
```

Вот хелловорд на яве. При запуске компиляции на NetBeans IDE 7.2. Выскакивает ошибка "Главный класс для проекта javalibrary1 не настроен".

Что делать? Как исправить?

Comment: Правой мыши по проекту - свойства - запуск (Run). Там есть кнопочка "Обзор" для выбора главного класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Kremchik](/users/2389/kremchik) а все разобрался, нужно было добавить класс в проект.